# Getting a request object as in a view function but called from `manage.py shell`

Tags: python, django

When I print a request object from a view function in `views.py` I get a  dictionary-like `django.core.handlers.wsgi.WSGIRequest` object(inherits from `django.http.HttpRequest`). Printing this dictionary-like object from a view function returns a bunch of values, especially for the `META` key.

Now I'd like to call this same data from the `manage.py shell` of my project but `handlers` is not an attribute of `django.core` in the shell so I cannot get the `django.core.handlers.wsgi.WSGIRequest` object. Is there any way of getting the request object as in my view function but called from the `manage.py shell`?

Comment: Why do you need it in a shell?

Comment: Really unsure about what you are trying to do here. But you can import the `WSGIRequest` in the shell: `from django.core.handlers.wsgi import WSGIRequest`.

Comment: Convenience, I'd like to access values from that dictionary-like object in the `manage.py shell`.

Comment: @John: How can I load the same values for the keys in `WSGIRequest` as from my views function? (To see those values I am talking about: just add `print request` in a view function and trigger that view function by going to the relevant url.)

Comment: @Bentley4 it sounds like you want to create `HttpRequest` objects. I'm still unsure as to why. Can you share a concrete example of what you want to achieve?

Comment: Just to replicate a request object and fiddle with it from the shell for introspection. I much prefer doing it like that than needing to adjust my `views.py` each time. You can populate models from views.py and you can also do it from the manage.py shell and introspect your models from there, so why wouldn't I want a similar feat for request objects.

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2036202/how-to-mock-users-and-requests-in-django

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your goal is to "*replicate a request object and fiddle with it from the shell for introspection*", the easiest way to accomplish fiddling with the request object is to use a debugger.

Copy paste the following into your view and reload it:

```
import pdb; pdb.set_trace()
```

Now reload the page pointing at that view & you can use [PDB's debugger commands](http://docs.python.org/library/pdb.html#debugger-commands) to exec your stuff. For example, inside a view function you can use `p request` to print the value of request, and you can also execute standard python code:

```
(Pdb) path = request.META['USERNAME']
(Pdb) h p
p expression
Print the value of the expression.
(Pdb) p path
'Caspar'
(Pdb) from foo.models import MyUser
(Pdb) MyUser.objects.all()
[<MyUser: Bob: 3.62810036125>, <MyUser: Tim: no rating>, <MyUser: Jim: 2.41014167534>, <MyUser: Rod: 1.35651839383>]
```

Even better, install [`ipdb`](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/ipdb) (`pip install ipdb`), which lets you use the much nicer [IPython](http://ipython.org/) shell, with fancy colors and tab completion.

Or, if you have no need for a debugger but just want an interactive console, install IPython (`pip install ipython`) and use the following snippet:

```
import IPython; IPython.embed()
```

Note that IPython is a prerequisite for ipdb, so installing ipdb will also install IPython.

Comment: I will accept this answer until a more elegant solution comes up.

Comment: @Bentley4 In the django documentation you have this well covered https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/testing/advanced/#the-request-factory