# What's the best way to mock a Django User?

Tags: django, python-3.x

I'm trying to instantiate a *User* instance through a Mock. That mock instance is being passed to another model *Profile* where I'm checking for any validation errors when a cleaning method is called.

However I'm getting: `AttributeError: Mock object has no attribute '_state'`

There is this previous post: [How to mock users and requests in django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2036202/how-to-mock-users-and-requests-in-django). Nevertheless, I want to avoid any database calls.

What can be done differently so that a Mock will in this case?

```
#models.py

class Profile(models.Model):

    hobby = "Hobbyist"
    develop = "Developer"
    coding_level = (
        (hobby, hobby),
        (develop, develop)
    )

    user = models.OneToOneField(
        settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE
    )
    birth = models.DateField(verbose_name="Date Of Birth")
    coding_level = models.CharField(
        verbose_name="Experience",
        max_length=20,
        choices=coding_level, default=hobby, blank=False
    )
    bio = models.TextField(
        verbose_name="User Bio",
        validators=[MinValueValidator(10)]
    )
    github = models.URLField(
        verbose_name="GitHub link",
        validators=[check_submitted_link],
        unique=True
    )
    avatar = models.ImageField(upload_to="images/%Y/%m/%d/")
```

```
#test_models.py

class TestProfile__001(SimpleTestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        self.test_user = Mock(
            spec=User,
            username="test_username",
            email="test@email.com"
        )

        self.profile_data = {
            'user': self.test_user,
            'birth': '2019-10-07',
            'coding_level': 'hobbyist',
            'bio': "",
            'github': "http://www.test.com",
            'avatar': "image.txt"
        }

    def test_create_profile_fail(self):
        with self.assertRaises(ValidationError):
            test_profile = Profile(**self.profile_data)
            test_profile.clean_fields()
```

Answer (score 0):

I would argue that there's no point in testing `clean_fields`, since it's [already a part](https://github.com/django/django/blob/54ea290e5bbd19d87bd8dba807738eeeaf01a362/django/db/models/base.py#L1223) of very well tested Django codebase. But if you insist on testing it, you are definitely should not mock the `User` out.

Let's look at the code you are trying to test here (this is an excerpt from [clean_fields](https://github.com/django/django/blob/54ea290e5bbd19d87bd8dba807738eeeaf01a362/django/db/models/base.py#L1223)):

```
        raw_value = getattr(self, f.attname)
        if f.blank and raw_value in f.empty_values:
            continue
        try:
            setattr(self, f.attname, f.clean(raw_value, self))
        except ValidationError as e:
            errors[f.name] = e.error_list
```

We see that it runs through every field on the model trying to call its `clean` method ([source](https://github.com/django/django/blob/f52022ad96356d4b1061610f2b74ea4d1956a608/django/forms/fields.py#L141)):

```
def clean(self, value):
    """
    Validate the given value and return its "cleaned" value as an
    appropriate Python object. Raise ValidationError for any errors.
    """
    value = self.to_python(value)
    self.validate(value)
    self.run_validators(value) 
    return value
```

`OneToOneField` itself does not introduce any of these methods, it's done higher in the class hierarchy, in `ForeignKey` class. And here's [the main part](https://github.com/django/django/blob/f52022ad96356d4b1061610f2b74ea4d1956a608/django/db/models/fields/related.py#L903) of the `validate` method:

```
    using = router.db_for_read(self.remote_field.model, instance=model_instance)
    qs = self.remote_field.model._default_manager.using(using).filter(
        **{self.remote_field.field_name: value}
    )
    qs = qs.complex_filter(self.get_limit_choices_to())
    if not qs.exists():
        raise exceptions.ValidationError(
            self.error_messages['invalid'],
            code='invalid',
            params={
                'model': self.remote_field.model._meta.verbose_name, 'pk': value,
                'field': self.remote_field.field_name, 'value': value,
            },  # 'pk' is included for backwards compatibility
        )
```

As you can see, the whole validation consists of nothing but a query construction with a database call! So if you are trying to avoid hitting the database, you should just skip the validation of any foreign keys altogether:

```
def test_create_profile_fail(self):
    with self.assertRaises(ValidationError):
        test_profile = Profile(**self.profile_data)
        test_profile.clean_fields(exclude=['user'])  # don't forget to explain your decision in the comments
```

So to conclude, the best way to mock the User is to actually create it in the database. If you want to avoid the boilerplate, you can use the [factory_boy package](https://factoryboy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/introduction.html).